# Grunt Contrib Compass Error on Mac Osx and rbenv

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos, rbenv

I'm on Mac Os 10.6, I'm using the Yeoman Angular Generator and within the `Package.json` there are `grunt-contrib-compass` and `grunt-contrib-watch`.

I have installed `rbenv`, `compass` and `sass` and the packages with `npm install` everything seems correct:

```
$: ruby -v
   ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin10.0]
$: compass -v
   Compass 0.12.6 (Alnilam)
$: sass -v 
   Sass 3.2.19 (Media Mark)
```

Nonetheless when I launch `grunt serve` I receive this error, weirdly referring to the wrong version of Ruby (1.8):

```
Warning: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19
from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/compass:23 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

`Ruby 1.8` is the standard pre-installed version on Snow Leopard, so I guess this problem is more related to `rbenv` even tough everything seems correctly installed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an `rbenv` misconfiguration.
In my `bash_profile` I was calling the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` way after the declaration of the rbenv shim path, so after all the other PATHs were added. This now works for me:

```
export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"

if [ -d $RBENV_ROOT ]; then
    PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```